# Sequelize. ERROR: null value in column "createdAt" violates not-null constraint

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm following the tutorial here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#creating-first-model-and-migration-

But when I do:

`node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:seed:all`

it gives to me:

```
ERROR: null value in column "createdAt" violates not-null constraint
```

I tested in a new `npm init` project with a new Postgres DB 10.4.

**Dialect:** postgres

**Dialect version:** "pg": "7.4.3",

**Database version:** 10.4

**Sequelize version:** "sequelize": "4.38.0"

Maybe this is a way to go? http://mmiyauchi.com/?p=2057

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer; for some reason createdAt and updatedAt were added to the SequelizeMeta table -- but the migration was adding a record to the SeqwuelizeMeta table without date values and it was THAT query that was breaking the migration.

Comment: How did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error for my case it's because i had a datas in my tables, to solve it i dumped all datas and run sequelize sync.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me using Sequelize + Postgres.

Adding to the [sequelize.define](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#using--a-href-----class-lib-sequelize-js-sequelize-html-instance-method-define---code-sequelize-define--code---a--) options parameter `timestamps: true` solved it.

Steps:

1. I Defined the columns `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, and `deletedAt` on the table creation (`queryInterface.createTable`).
2. On the model definition options object (`sequelize.define(modelName, attributes, options)`), **I forgot `timestamps: true`**.